# Accessing Javascript Object with Key

Tags: javascript

I have the following object `self.originalData` on the console:

[image]

However, when I try to access to first object in the array of `originalData`,

`self.originalData[0hcMSJXljH]`

getting the following error

> the Uncaught>Syntax Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

I could not able to figure out where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Enclose the index in quotes if you're directly accessing it.

Comment: Very closely related, but coming at it from the other side: [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
self.originalData["0hcMSJXljH"]
```

instead.  Object keys are strings so if you use the `[]` notation, then you have to put a string or a variable that contains a string inside the brackets.

Your particular case is a bit unusual because usually, you can use the dot notation as in `obj.property`, but because your key starts with a number, it is not a legal identifier to use with the dot notation (you can't do `self.originalData.0hcMSJXljH`).  So, you are forced to use the bracket notation with that particular key.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the key in quotes like this:

```
self.originalData['0hcMSJXljH']
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
self.originalData["0hcMSJXljH"];
```

?

<s>Otherwise:</s>

```
self.originalData.0hcMSJXljH;
```

EDIT: last one not possible because the first char is a number, as explained to me

Comment: You can't do the second one.  Identifiers used with the dot notation in Javascript cannot start with a number.

Comment: Yep, I noticed from your answers, my bad

Answer (score 1):

You must use quotes:

```
self.originalData['0hcMSJXljH']
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use quotes in your key, so it seems you are trying to use the *variable identified by* `0hcMSJXljH` as the key. However, `0hcMSJXljH` isn't a valid variable identifier, because it begins with a number, so your get an illegal-character error.

Simply use a string, not an identifier:

```
self.originalData["0hcMSJXljH"]
```